# Meeting WCAG AAA criteria - worth mentioning?

Tags: accessibility, wcag

I have been asked to critique a site... while doing the colour contrast accessibility test, I found out that a few things don't meet the WCAG AAA criteria. Is this something I should bring up? Or will I look like a total fool? It is an educational website...

Comment: Are you doing this for a contract, or do you work for the institution? Does the contract say what level of to meet? Does the institution have an accessibility policy, which metions what level to meet? I don't know figures, but a fair number of places use AA as acceptable level. I would weigh how big the errors are, and how much they would take to fix them as a basis what to bring up

Comment: *Why* should you not?

Comment: I'm very late to this - but I would first find out what the goal is of the organization, many accept AA as the standard to meet.  AAA is a worthy goal, but if the organization is only trying to achieve a lower standard then bringing up AAA violations are not going to benefit you.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that the prime criterion comes from the stake holder.  If they have a level they want to achieve then I'd document the AAA issues in an appendix and address the levels they care about directly.

I would caveat that many clients do not have a clear view of what the levels mean and what the impact may be.  For example there are some criteria that are AA/AAA because we could not define automatable tests for them.  This was a compromise to the reality of high volume publishers where only automation is feasible.

Thus as an educational institution they me be subject to requirements that aren't fully captured in WCAG.  Yes the 503 refresh largely makes WCAG the de facto rubric for assessment but the institution may have internal support requirements, e.g. note taking assistance, that would require some of these AA/AAA criteria be met.

So yes the organizations goals determine what you bring up and recommend mitigations for, but the broader goals may raise some issues importance for them.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: https://www.wuhcag.com/wcag-level-aaa/

Achievable with impact

```
1.2.8 – Media Alternative (Pre-recorded)
1.4.6 – Contrast (Enhanced)
1.4.7 – Low or no Background Audio
1.4.8 – Visual Presentation
1.4.9 – Images of Text (No Exception)
2.2.3 – No Timing
2.3.2 – Three flashes
2.4.8 – Location
2.4.9 – Link Purpose (Link Only)
3.2.5 – Change on Request
3.3.5 – Help
3.3.6 – Error Prevention (All)
```

May not be realistic

```
1.2.7 – Extended Audio Description (Pre-recorded)
2.1.3 – Keyboard (No Exception)
2.2.4 – Interruptions
2.2.5 – Re-authenticating
2.4.10 – Section headings
3.1.3 – Unusual Words
3.1.4 – Abbreviations
3.1.5 – Reading Level
3.1.6 – Pronunciation
```

Unlikely to be possible

```
1.2.6 – Sign Language (Pre-recorded)
1.2.9 – Audio Only (Live)
```